# Why snippets include error with spring-restdocs-asciidoctor?

Tags: asciidoctor, spring-restdocs

i do can generate the index.html when i using spring-restdocs with asciidoctor, but it cannot generate request or response like this.

```
== /hello: Say "Hello World!"

operation::hello[]

.request
include::{snippets}/hello/http-request.adoc[]

.response
include::{snippets}/hello/http-response.adoc[]
```

here is my config files.

maven dependencies

```
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Add Log4j2 Dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Needed for Async Logging with Log4j 2 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.lmax</groupId>
        <artifactId>disruptor</artifactId>
        <version>${disruptor.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-restdocs-mockmvc</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.asciidoctor</groupId>
            <artifactId>asciidoctor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${asciidoctor.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-docs</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process-asciidoc</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <backend>html</backend>
                        <doctype>book</doctype>
                        <sourceHighlighter>prettify</sourceHighlighter>
                        <attributes>
                            <toc>left</toc>
                            <icons>font</icons>
                            <sectanchors>true</sectanchors>
                            <idprefix/>
                        </attributes>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-restdocs-asciidoctor</artifactId>
                    <version>${spring-restdocs.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-resources-plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-resources</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>
                            ${project.build.outputDirectory}/static/docs
                        </outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>
                                    ${project.build.directory}/generated-docs
                                </directory>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                    <version>${junit.platform.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

this is `index.adoc`

```
= blog
:doctype: book
:icons: font
:source-highlighter: highlightjs

== /hello: Say "Hello World!"

operation::hello[]

.request
include::{snippets}/hello/http-request.adoc[]

.response
include::{snippets}/hello/http-response.adoc[]
```

this is my test class

```java
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ExtendWith({RestDocumentationExtension.class, SpringExtension.class})
public class HelloControllerTest {
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp(WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext,
                      RestDocumentationContextProvider restDocumentation) {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext)
                .apply(documentationConfiguration(restDocumentation))
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void hello() throws Exception {

        mockMvc.perform(get("/hello").param("name", "imckh"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.msg", "Hello imckh!").exists())
                .andDo(document("hello",
                        requestParameters(parameterWithName("name").description("The name to retrieve")),
                        responseFields(
                                fieldWithPath("code").description("Code of the response"),
                                fieldWithPath("msg").description("Message of the response"))
                ));
    }
}
```

When i done testing, it can generate some `*.adoc` files like 'http-request.adoc, http-response.adoc', 
[generated-snippets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNFU9.png)
then i use maven package, it do can generate a `index.html`, but it cannot parse below

```
operation::hello[]

.request
include::{snippets}/hello/http-request.adoc[]

.response
include::{snippets}/hello/http-response.adoc[]
```

[generated docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9SvM.png)

It get wrong in this step: [Including multiple snippets for an operation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-restdocs/docs/2.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html5/#working-with-asciidoctor-including-snippets-operation)

Thanks.

Comment: I can't spot anything that looks incorrect in how you've set things up. Could you turn your pom, adoc, and test code snippets into something that's complete and reproduces the problem? A repository on GitHub that can be cloned and built would be ideal.

Comment: U can `git checkout restdocs-fix` to check this problem.
here is GitHub repo [imckh/git-blog at restdocs-fix](https://github.com/imckh/git-blog/tree/restdocs-fix)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using version 2.0.0-RC.1 of `asciidoctor-maven-plugin` with which `spring-restdocs-asciidoctor` is not compatible. Unfortunately, that incompatibility results in a silent failure to resolve the generated snippets. If you downgrade to 1.6.0 you will at least see a failure caused by the incompatibility.

You can avoid the problem by using a 1.5.x version of `asciidoctor-maven-plugin` with which `spring-restdocs-asciidoctor` in compatible. At the time of writing, 1.5.8 is the latest version. Things work as expected with this version.

You may also be interested in [this Spring REST Docs issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-restdocs/issues/581) which will hopefully figure out what to do about the breaking changes in AsciidoctorJ once the dust has settled a bit.